# Other types of planetary systems?

Tags: science-based, planets, space, astronomy

I recently watched [Artifexian’s video about other planetary systems,](https://youtu.be/SCz6JY-24Yo) and I’d like to know more about those types mentioned and if there are any additional types I should know about. (I’ve heard that classical planetary systems aren’t common, which is why I want to learn about and probably make another type). I’ve been doing research in this area for a while, but can’t find anything helpful.

My question is: could you share some **sources that explain other types of planetary systems in more detail,** as well as sources explaining **how I could make my own system of each type?** I’m specifically looking for info on **any types that could support life.**
Also, I’d like to request that you simplify any information you present to a non-astronomer/non-mathematician level. Thank you in advance!

Here are the types mentioned in the video:
Hot Jupiter systems,
Frost line systems,
Long period systems,
Compact systems (STIPS?),
Dusty systems,
Failed sun systems,
Tatooine systems

Comment: Welcome Xirvek. This is way too broad and open-ended for the way our site works. We address single clearly focused questions where criteria are clear enough that a single identifiable "best answer" can be identified. What you're asking is for an unconstrained list. Please review the [help]'se [ask] section. Enjoy the site.

Comment: Hello Xirvek. You're asking us to take volumes of complex information and reduce them to a non-specialist's level on your behalf. Giving you a high-school-level summary of 2-3 college-level astronomy classes isn't within the scope of Stack Exchange. You might get an answer over at [astronomy.se], but you should expect that they're not going to simplify everything for you, either. But they might know of a document that summarizes what you're looking for, which might be simple enough.